# How to open TortoiseGit "Working Tree" window from the command line?

Tags: windows, git, command-line, tortoisegit

### Context

The picture below shows the manual process I use to show a Git working tree changes with TortoiseGit GUI on Windows.

The process is:

1. Right click the root folder of a local git repository.
2. Hover over option "TortoiseGit".
3. Select option "Diff".

[image]

By following these steps, TortoiseGit shows a "Working Tree" window dialog like the one below:

[image]

### Question

Is it possible to show this same window from the command line on Windows? How could one open TortoiseGit "Working Tree" window from Git bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `TortoiseGitProc /path:THEPATH /command:repostatus`

In some cases you can omit `/path:`

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-automation.html